# How to use send method to post, get, update route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm trying to DRY some request specs.
I need to pass to a shared example the following params:

```
method, action, params
```

shared_example:

```
shared_context "blah" do |method, action, params|
  let(:url_path) { send("api_cars_path") }
end
```

How can I execute a route with send using the method that is being passed as parameter ? Something like this:

```
send(:get, "api_cars_path")
```

So I can can pass :get, :post, etc dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

The route api_cars_path is really a method which returns a string like `/api/cars`. So you need to invoke the route helper and then pass it to the get method as the first argument.

```
send(:get, send(:api_cars_path))
```